# PHP сгруппировать массив по значению

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида

```
$array = [
            ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 3],
            ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 2],
            ['group_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1],
        ];
```

Нужно сгруппировать его элементы по group_id чтобы на выходе получился вот такой массив:

```
$result = [['group_id' => 2, 'element_id'=> [3,2]], ['group_id' => 1,'element_id'=>[1]]];
```

Важно что бы на получившийся массив имел точно такую структуру как я описал. Кто в курсе как красиво это реализовать?

UPD. Хорошее рабочее решение предложил тов. Becouse. Чуть подправленный вариант (более лаконичный) приведу ниже:

```
function group_by($array, $key, $res)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $return[$key][$val[$key]][$res][] = $val[$res];
    }

    $func = function ($array, $first, $second) {
        $result=array();
        foreach($array[$first] as $key=>$val){
            $a=array();
            $a[$first]=$key;
            $a[$second]=$val[$second];
            $result[]=$a;
        }
        return $result;
    };

    return $func($return, $key, $res);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант.

Вспомогательная функция

```
function _group_by_elements($array, $first, $second){
 $result=array();
 foreach($array[$first] as $key=>$val){
   $a=array();
   $a[$first]=$key;
   $a[$second]=$val[$second];
   $result[]=$a;
  }
 return $result;
}
```

Основная функция

```
function _group_by($array, $key, $res) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $return[$key][$val[$key]][$res][] = $val[$res];
    }
    return _group_by_elements($return, $key, $res);
}
```

исходный преобразуем в

```
['group_id'=>[2=>['element_id'=> [3,2]], 1=>'element_id'=>[1]]]
```

Затем `_group_by_elements` в другой формат

```
[['group_id' => 2, 'element_id'=> [3,2]], ['group_id' => 1,'element_id'=>[1]]]
```

Пример

```
$list = [
            ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 3],
            ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 2],
            ['group_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1],
        ];

$group=_group_by($list, 'group_id','element_id');

print_r($group);
```

Comment: А совпадает ли это с тем что ждет автор?

Comment: @u_mulder да, вполне. Даже удобнее для практического использования.

Comment: Вообще-то не совпадает.

Comment: @u_mulder ну из такого представления легко в любой формат. Добавил.

Comment: Полностью подходит под условие. Благодарю. Выбрал этот вариант правильным потому как для практического использования реально удобнее.

Comment: Единственное, что я бы подправил, это вспомогательную функцию сделал анонимной внутри основной.

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php
$array = [
    ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 3],
    ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 2],
    ['group_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item){
    if(count($result) > 0){
        $have = 0;
        foreach ($result as $key=>$val){
            if (in_array($item['group_id'], $val)){
                array_push($result[$key]['element_id'], $item['element_id']);
            } else {
                $have = 1;
            }
        }
        if($have == 1){
            $tempArr = [];
            $tempArr['group_id'] = $item['group_id'];
            $tempArr['element_id'] = array($item['element_id']);
            array_push($result, $tempArr);
        }
    } else {
        $tempArr = [];
        $tempArr['group_id'] = $item['group_id'];
        $tempArr['element_id'] = array($item['element_id']);
        array_push($result, $tempArr);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Вроде как если заменить array_push($result, $tempArr); на конструкцию типа $result[] = $tempArr будет работать быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
    ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 3],
    ['group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 2],
    ['group_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $groupId = $item['group_id'];
    if (!isset($result[$groupId])) {
        $result[$groupId] = ['group_id' => $groupId, 'element_id'=> []];
    }
    $result[$groupId]['element_id'][] = $item['element_id'];
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$array = array(
            array('group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 3),
            array('group_id' => 2, 'element_id' => 2),
            array('group_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1),
        );


$result = [array('group_id' => '2', 'element_id'=> array('3','2')), array('group_id' => '1','element_id'=>array('1'))];

print_r($result);
echo '------';

$result1=array(array('group_id' => $array[0]['group_id'], 'element_id'=> array($array[0]['element_id'], $array[0]['group_id'])), array('group_id'=> $array[2]['group_id'], 'element_id'=>array($array[2]['element_id'])));

print_r($result1);

?>
```