# Перебор массива php объединение

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть массивы с данными. Например

```
[
company_id = 3,
email = pupkin@mail.ru
],
[
company_id = 2,
email = biba@mail.ru
],
[
company_id = 3,
email = beaver@mail.ru
]
```

В случае когда company_id одинаковое, надо объединить массивы сделав в поле email записи из обоих

Comment: это стандартный вопрос, на него уже полно ответов, даже писать не стоит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP сгруппировать массив по значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095355/php-%d1%81%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы если company_id совпадает то в поле e-mail должен быть массив а не строковое значение или как?

Comment: Если компани айди совпадает то в поле емейл хоть массив хоть строка хоть джсон, я не понимаю самой логики как это высроить по шагам. То что вы предложили похоже на правду, но почему-то не заработало.

Comment: Вот сейчас еще раз попробовал получается почему-то 4 массива, 3 из них с одинаковыми company_id, но разным количеством почт

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону функции array_merge($ar1,$ar2,$ar3); Возможно после этого ещё вызвать функцию array_unique() чтобы остались только уникальные значения. Может быть ещё имеет смысл привести значения к нижнему регистру используя strtolower(); а уже после её вызывать array_unique();.

Ответ дополнен с этого места с учётом информации уточнённой у автора вопроса в комментариях:

```
<?php
$a = array(["company_id"=>3,"email"=>"pupkin@mail.ru"],
["company_id"=>2,"email"=>"biba@mail.ru"],
["company_id"=>3,"email"=>"beaver@mail.ru"]);

function mySearchElement(&$arToSearch=false,$companyId=false) {
  if (($companyId !== false) and is_array($arToSearch)) {
    foreach ($arToSearch as $key => $itemAr) {
      if ($itemAr["company_id"] == $companyId) {
        return $key;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$newAr = array();
foreach ($a as $itemAr) {var_dump($itemAr);
  if (($key = mySearchElement($newAr,$itemAr["company_id"])) !== false) {
    if (!in_array(($tmp = strtolower(trim($itemAr["email"]))),$newAr[$key]["email"])) {
      $newAr[$key]["email"][] = $tmp;
    }
  } else {
    $newAr[] = array("company_id"=>$itemAr["company_id"],"email"=>array(strtolower(trim($itemAr["email"]))));
  }
}
echo "<p>\n";
var_dump($newAr);
echo "</p>\n";
```

var_dump выглядят следующим образом:

array(2) { ["company_id"]=> int(3) ["email"]=> string(14) "pupkin@mail.ru" } array(2) { ["company_id"]=> int(2) ["email"]=> string(12) "biba@mail.ru" } array(2) { ["company_id"]=> int(3) ["email"]=> string(14) "beaver@mail.ru" }

array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["company_id"]=> int(3) ["email"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "pupkin@mail.ru" [1]=> string(14) "beaver@mail.ru" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["company_id"]=> int(2) ["email"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "biba@mail.ru" } } }

Comment: array_unique() не поможет. Судя по всему, company_id совпадают, а почты разные

Comment: @skvernoslov А что вы ожидаете после array_merge ?

Comment: Это замечательные функции, вот только мне не понятен алгоритм обработки данных.  С чего начать, как сравнивать и т.д.

Comment: @splash58, предположил что нужны вообще все почты из массива а не группировка по company_id, если бы это было так тогда первым циклом пройтись по всем ключам e-mail и в новый массив их записать, а потом array_unique оставить уникальные. Тут же видимо задача на группировку. Я подумал что первые скобки [] это отдельные массивы в отдельных переменных, и чтобы собрать в один массив с которым потом работать в цикле предложил объединить с использованием array_merge.

Comment: @Stieglits, дополнил ответ вариантом кода предположительно для Вашего случая.